# I'm having difficulty installing pdftotext for python

Tags: python, pdftotext, poppler

I am trying to install `pdftotext`, but I keep receiving the same error even after installing the visual tools.

This happens for both `pip install` and I am just trying to find it in my directory...

*Terminal output below:*

```
C:\Users\garec\Downloads>pip3 install pdftotext-2.1.4.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\garec\downloads\pdftotext-2.1.4.tar.gz
Using legacy setup.py install for pdftotext, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pdftotext
    Running setup.py install for pdftotext ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\garec\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-9ov7_rup\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\garec\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-9ov7_rup\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4zlbnvu1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pdftotext'
         cwd: C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9ov7_rup\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    WARNING: pkg-config not found--guessing at poppler version.
             If the build fails, install pkg-config and try again.
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pdftotext' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\garec\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-9ov7_rup\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\garec\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-9ov7_rup\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4zlbnvu1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\garec\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pdftotext' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

try `brew install pkg-config poppler` before you do `pip install pdftotext` (: